# Folder of 24 gigs has only 12 gigs nested. How to account for mysterious bloat?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I have a `~/Library/Developer` used by Xcode.app in El Capitan. The `Finder` > `Get Info` reports a size of 24 gigs. But the two nested folders each report only 6 gigs each. So ( 2 * 6 ) = 12, and ( 24 - 12 ) = 12. Where is the other 12 mysterious gigs?

I am showing invisible files/folders. So I believe I have not overlooked any other content. I did recently delete much content from there, and emptied the Trash.

How can I track down this huge discrepancy?

Using the `du`, the “display disk usage statistics” tool, where `-d` is depth (Display an entry for all files and directories depth directories deep) and `-h` is "Human-readable" output (Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte).

**Outer folder:**

```bash
cd ~/Library; du -d 1 -h;
```

```
…
 11G    ./Developer
…
```

**Inner folders:**

```bash
cd ~/Library/Developer; du -d 1 -h;
```

```
706M    ./CoreSimulator
4.4G    ./Shared
5.9G    ./Xcode
 11G    .
```

cd ~/Library; du -d 1 -h;

But the `Get Info` reports twice that, 24.x gigs.

Comment: What does `cd ~/Library/Developer;du -d 1 -h` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Use [`du`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) tool to see the truth.
- Or, maybe wait a couple of hours.

## Details

While shooting a screenshot of the Finder > Get Info showing 24 gigs and the results of the `du` command-line tool showing only 11 gigs, the Get Info panel changed with an automatic update. This was after a reboot and after 1-2 hours of repeatedly showing 24 gigs.

So the Finder must be caching information about the folders long after deleting gigs of data in a large numbers of files.

As suggested by [tubedogg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/54484/tubedogg), use the [`du` command-line tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) to see accurate readings of your folder sizes.